# How do I get data from an alias column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to calculate based on an alias column.

```
SELECT 
    Aged, NotAged, Aging
FROM
    (SELECT 
         DATEDIFF(DAY, CASE WHEN Stat = 'HOLD' THEN Created ELSE Opened END,
                      CASE WHEN Stat = 'Closed' THEN Closed ELSE GETDATE() END) AS Aged,
         DATEDIFF(DAY, CASE WHEN Aged <= 25 THEN GETDATE() AS NotAged ELSE GETDATE() END) AS Aging
     FROM 
         DM.Claim 
     INNER JOIN
         DM.LDesc ON LDescKey = LDescKey) data
```

How do I go about calculating based on an alias column to get `NotAged` and `Aging`?

Expected output would be
Aged {1 2 35} NotAged {1 2} Aging {35}

Comment: `THEN GETDATE() AS NotAged` isn't valid syntax. You can't alias an expression within a `CASE` expression.

Comment: @Larnu you have an idea on how to calculate based on an alias column? I'm trying to filter the alias column based on the values it returns and have two separate columns for each filter.

Comment: It's difficult to determine what you're trying to do with this query. Do you have sample data and expected output?

Comment: expected output would be

Comment: @Isolated Expected output would be IF 1-100 return Aged, if aged is <=25 return not aged ELSE return Aging. Trying to calculate if the alias column Aged is really aging or not based on the numbers it returns

Comment: That isn't sample data, not expected results, @OEGM2002 . [Edit] your question to add this.

Comment: Are you looking for delimited data then? And, where is the sample data that has been asked for .?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299484/good-examples-of-database-questions-providing-some-sample-data-in-the-question and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question, we need proper sample data and expected results in a clear format

Comment: Expect output is only useful if you provide the input that goes with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Charlieface's suggestion to use CROSS APPLY does the trick.
Another option is using CTE (common table expressions), so calculated (and aliased) columns can be used in expressions downstream.
Here is an example with some made up data.

```
with somedata as (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM ( values
        ('HOLD', '2022-06-01', '2022-06-02', '2022-07-15'),
        ('HOLD', '2022-07-01', '2022-07-02', '2022-07-15'),
        ('Closed', '2022-06-01', '2022-06-02', '2022-07-15'),
        ('Closed', '2022-07-01', '2022-07-02', '2022-07-15')
    ) vals (Stat, Created, Opened, Closed)
)
,
precalc as (
    select
        *,
        Aged = DATEDIFF(
            DAY,
            CASE WHEN Stat = 'HOLD' THEN Created ELSE Opened END,
            CASE WHEN Stat = 'Closed' THEN Closed ELSE GETDATE() END
        )
    from somedata
)
SELECT 
    Aged,
    NotAged = case when Aged <25 then Aged end,
    Aging = case when Aged >=25 then Aged end,
    *
FROM precalc
```

Output (20220721)

| Aged | NotAged | Aging | Stat | Created | Opened | Closed | Aged |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | NULL | 50 | HOLD | 2022-06-01 | 2022-06-02 | 2022-07-15 | 50 |
| 20 | 20 | NULL | HOLD | 2022-07-01 | 2022-07-02 | 2022-07-15 | 20 |
| 43 | NULL | 43 | Closed | 2022-06-01 | 2022-06-02 | 2022-07-15 | 43 |
| 13 | 13 | NULL | Closed | 2022-07-01 | 2022-07-02 | 2022-07-15 | 13 |

Comment: this the output I want but what is precalc? @shortski

Comment: I got it now, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Without sample data and expected results it's hard to say for sure what you want (aggregation?), but you can use `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` to create a calculated column, and you can even chain them by referring to a previous one. For example.

```sql
SELECT 
    v1.Aged,
    v1.NotAged,
    v2.Aging
FROM
    DM.Claim AS c
INNER JOIN
    DM.LDesc AS ld ON ld.LDescKey = c.LDescKey
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    DATEDIFF(DAY, CASE WHEN Stat = 'HOLD' THEN Created ELSE Opened END,
                  CASE WHEN Stat = 'Closed' THEN Closed ELSE GETDATE() END,
    CASE WHEN Aged <= 25 THEN GETDATE() END
) ) AS v1(Aged, NotAged)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    DATEDIFF(DAY, v1.NotAged ELSE GETDATE() END, v1.Aged)
) ) AS v2(Aging);
```